# How to continuously fadeIn() each character of an element text, including nested elements, without losing formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My client force me to use some of script which he used on his previous site for slowly and smoothly loading text of a article. Script works, but the problem is that the formatting (`<strong>`) is lost somewhere and instead of three different paragraphs I've got all together three times...

**HTML**

```
<article id="post-5" class="post-5 page type-page status-publish hentry" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 400px;">
  <div class="col-6 column">                      
    <p><strong>Je mi přes 40 a jsem žena.</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Snažila jsem se zařadit, zmoudřet a mít klid. Nepodařilo se.</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Teď se už předělávat nehodlám. A víte co? Strašně si to užívám. Prozkoumávám svou zběsilost v srdci, ženskou marnivost i potřebu mít věci pod kontrolou. Zjistila jsem, že svět je báječné místo k žití, že život není vždycky fér, ale c´est la vie, že být sexy neznamená být krásná, že být úspěšná, neznamená být chytrá, že když se člověk nebere smrtelně vážně, tak je to vlastně skvělá jízda a že můj “bucketlist” je zatraceně dlouhý. Také, že když se nám “povedou” děti, věříme na geny, ale když jsou děti svérázné a my čelíme neustále zvednutému obočí okolí a máme pocit selhání – je lepší nechat to být a doufat, že se dobré geny nakonec “proberou”, protože to jediné, na čem opravdu záleží, jsou hodnoty a důvěra v sebe i svět okolo nás, neopomíjet tu krásu a čistotu, která dětství provází, tu lásku, kterou jsme schopni získat i dávat a užít si čas, který nám byl dán. Svět je plný silných příběhů a skvělých lidí a já jsem se rozhodla, že v čase, který mi byl vyměřen, je chci potkávat, chci se jimi inspirovat a tuto inspiraci předávat dál.</p>                  
  </div>
</article>
```

**Javascript**

```
var header = $('.post-5 div p');

var title = header.text();
header.text('');        

var arrayTitle = title.split('');
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (i > arrayTitle.length) {
        setTimeout(function(title) {
            header.text(title);
        }, 1000, title);
        //header.text(title);
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        $('<span>')
        .text(arrayTitle[i])
        .appendTo(header)
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1000);

        i++;      
    }
}, 30);
```

And here you go with [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPgaaj?editors=101) and you can see what it does to the text. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) the problem is that the formatting (`<strong>`) is lost somewhere (...)

The `.text()` method returns pure text of the element (and its descendants), without tags.
To get the text including tags, jQuery has a `.html()` method. However this would not work with your code either (unless using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)). It's because you're exploding the text to individual characters:

```
var arrayTitle = title.split('');
```

Then all the characters are wraped into `<span>`:

```
$('<span>')
  .text(arrayTitle[i])
  //...
```

So, even using `.html()` where the tags are not wiped out, each character of the tag will be wrapped into `<span>` element, so that it will results as following (`<strong>`) :

```
<span>&lt;</span>
<span>s</span>
<span>t</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>g</span>
<span>&gt;</span>
...
```

> (...) instead of three different paragraphs I've got all together three times

That's the result of these lines:

```
var header = $('.post-5 div p');
var title = header.text();
```

What's actually happening there, is that `header` points to an object containing all of the `<p>` elements.
The `title` is a text pulled from all of the elements inside that object.
Therefore each item inside `header` (each `<p>`) gets filled in with text of all three `<p>` elements.

---

### Solution

You would need to loop through the `<p>` elements to process each of them separately:

```
$('.post-5 div p').each(function(){
    // $(this) points to the current <p> element instead of all:
    var header = $(this);
    // ...
});
```

This could get you closer if the code is supposed to work **only** with the strictly specified HTML markup.
Then you could use an `if` statement to check some conditions and run your original code:

```
// declare current timeout variable:
var delay = 0;
$('.post-5 div p').each(function(){
    // declare <strong> element as current 'header':
    var header = $(this).find('strong');
    // if it's not found:
    if(!header.length){
        // declare <p> instead as current 'header':
        header = $(this);
    }

    // ... your code ...

    // Then wrap your setInterval with a setTimeout to not fade each <p> at once:
    setTimeout(function(){
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            // ... your code ...
        }, 30);
    // set timeout on which the current 'header' should start fading:    
    },delay);
    // update delay for the next <p> element:
    delay += 30*arrayTitle.length;
});
```

That's a quick fix for your code, considering it to work with a static HTML markup.

[**Additional way**](http://jsfiddle.net/vv8j0oLm/) (cleaner)

---

### Another solution

In order to get the code work with content that has multiple nested tags, at first place you should separate texts and elements to make your tags intact.
it can be done using `.contents()` (jQuery) and `nodeType` (javascript)

`.contents()` returns an array of children elements, and for that HTML example:

```
Hello <b>World</b> <span>Foo Bar</span>
```

The result will be:

```
nodeType:3  |  nodeType:1  |  nodeType:3  |  nodeType:1
 [Hello ]   |   [World]    |     [ ]      |  [Foo Bar]
```

You can then loop through that array and wrap characters into `<span>` only if `nodeType === 3` , otherwise run function again for that node:

```
function spanifyText(el){
    $(el).contents().each(function(){
        // check if the element is not a text node:
        if(this.nodeType !== 3){
            // not a text node, run method again for that element:
            return spanifyText(this);
        }
        // it's a text node. Process it:
        $(this).replaceWith('<span class="fade">'+$(this).text().split('').join('</span><span class="fade">')+'</span>');
    });
}
spanifyText('.post-5 div p');
// after processing, hide each character and fade it:
$('.fade').hide().each(function(i){
    $(this).delay(i*30).fadeIn(function(){
        // unwrap the character after animation, so that it is no longer inside a <span>:
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/srrxre39/)

---

### References

- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)
- [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)
- [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/nodeType)

Answer (score 0):

The .text() grabs the text not the html. Use .html()

```
$('.post-5 div p');
```

gives three results not just one.

If you want to use the same effect you will have to modify completely the script.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I'm really not goon in the js, could you please help me